# A random inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let $A \in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ be abitrary and $B\in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ be symmetric (not sure if necessary). Then is the following inequality true?
$$
|(AB)_{ii}|^2+|(A^*B)_{ii}|^2 +2\Re(A_{ii} (B^*A^*B)_{ii})\ge0
$$
for all $i=1,2,...,n$.

This probably seems random, but I stumbled across this during some calculations. If the following were true, it would greatly simplify my calculations. A quick test using random matrices on a computer seems to always give me a $\ge 0$ value, but I can't think of why it would be true in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, then $AB=A^*B=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, $B^*A^*B=BAB=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}$, so the inequality is false for $i=1$.

What one can show is the following:

$$0\le|\langle x,ABx\rangle+\langle x,A^*Bx\rangle|^2=|\langle x,ABx\rangle|^2+|\langle x,A^*Bx\rangle|^2+2\mathrm{Re}\langle ABx,x\rangle\langle x,A^*Bx\rangle$$ in particular for $x=e_i$, so that $\langle e_i,ABe_i\rangle=(AB)_{ii}$, etc.

Moreover, if $A$ is positive self-adjoint, then by Cauchy-Schwarz, $$|\langle x,Ay\rangle|^2\le\langle x,Ax\rangle\langle y,Ay\rangle$$
Hence putting $y=Bx$ gives $$|\langle x,ABx\rangle|^2\le\langle x,Ax\rangle \langle x,B^*ABx\rangle$$ so the given inequality is again (trivially) true.